# Differences in tensor products under change of ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

In his book "Algebra: Chapter 0", Paolo Aluffi gave the following exercise:
[image]

which prompts the following question: under which circumstance(s) does the the tensor product change with the change of ring ?

Comment: Is Aluffi asking about isomorphism as $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces? As $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces? As rings? As $\mathbb{R}$-algebras?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I'm pretty sure as modules

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the tensor product does not change precisely when the morphism of rings $R\to S$ is an epimorphism. The reason is that the tensor product over $S$ is constructed by balancing the tensor product over $R$ with respect to the $S$-action. But if the morphism is an epimorphism, the $S$-action is uniquely determined by the $R$-action and the tensor product over $R$ must therefore already be $S$-balanced.